# npm start TypeError Cannot Detect node version

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, npm

I am trying to run a react app using npm start. I'm using node js 10.24.1 and cannot upgrade it as the project is a legacy project.
I tried clear the cache with force, removing node_modules and package-lock.json, nothing worked. I also tried using gulp tasks as the porject requires running backend tasks using gulp run:backend. After that, I use gulp run:dar-360. dar-360 being the name of my app.
There are no errors in the console, however the application doesn't start in the browser and the chrome devtools show:

```
index.js:57 Uncaught TypeError: Unable to determine current node version
   at versionIncluded (index.js:57:1)
   at isCore (index.js:76:1)
   at ../../node_modules/resolve/lib/core.js (core.js:12:1)
   at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:784:1)
   at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
   at ../../node_modules/resolve/index.js (index.js:3:1)
   at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:784:1)
   at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
   at ../../node_modules/tslint/lib/utils.js (utils.js:25:1)
   at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:784:1)
   at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
   at ./src/modules/maps/pages/map-page/components/help-modal.component.js (geo.helper.js:122:1)
   at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:784:1)
   at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
   at ./src/modules/maps/pages/map-page/map.page.js (map.page.css:45:1)
   at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:784:1)
   at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
   at ./src/components/app/app.component.js (app.component.css:45:1)
   at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:784:1)
   at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
   at ./src/index.js (index.css:45:1)
   at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:784:1)
   at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
   at 1 (service-worker.utils.js:56:1)
   at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:784:1)
   at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45:1)
   at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32:1)
   at main.chunk.js:1:67
```

Comment: `I'm using node js 10.24.1` - so TEN major releases old ... time to upgrade?

Comment: This project is 5 years old contains 5 different react apps so upgrading would cause many errors. Besides, the error is new.

Comment: `the error is new` - so, after an upgrade to something in your project

Answer (score 0):

You need to Add **C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe;** and **C:\Users{yourName}\AppData\Roaming\npm;** to your PATH environment variable. To do this follow these steps:

1. Use the global Search Charm to search "Environment Variables"
2. Click "Edit system environment variables"
3. Click "Environment Variables" in the dialog.
4. In the "System Variables" box, search for Path and edit it to
   include **C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe; C:\Users{yourName}\AppData\Roaming\npm;** Make sure it is separated from any
   other paths by a ;.

You will have to restart any currently-opened command prompts before it will take effect.

This should read your node version while running your local server, this solution is for windows only

Comment: Hey thanks for helping
I am using nvm and when i open any cmd and run node -v i get v10.24.1 it's working fine with my other react apps